# Weird Adonis2 output in R: by="Margin" results in a R2 of 0, F of -Inf, and no P-value for 1 factor

Tags: r, vegan

I'm running a PERMANOVA analysis using vegan's `adonis2`. I have (rarefied) fungal community data (18S sequencing) of 24 samples. As treatments I have subplot (1,2,3,4,5 or 6) and state (con and sup). Each subplot has 4 samples and a subplot is seen as either 'con' or 'sup'. Thus metadata looking like:

[image]

To perform the PERMANOVA analysis and test marginal effect of the variables, I run following command:

```
adonis2(vegan_abundance_mat ~ factor(state) + factor(subplot), by="margin", data=vegan_sample_data, permutations = 1000,method="bray")
```

Which yields:

```
Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Marginal effects of terms
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 1000

adonis2(formula = vegan_abundance_mat ~ factor(state) + factor(subplot), data = vegan_sample_data, permutations = 1000, method = "bray", by = "margin")
                Df SumOfSqs      R2      F   Pr(>F)    
factor(state)    0  0.00000 0.00000   -Inf             
factor(subplot)  4  0.28593 0.28305 1.8711 0.000999 ***
Residual        18  0.68767 0.68075                    
Total           23  1.01017 1.00000                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**Why does my "state" variable, get this weird output as stated in the title of this topic?**

If I add the terms sequentially to the model, the output looks 'normal':

```
adonis2(vegan_abundance_mat ~ factor(state) + factor(subplot), by="terms",data=vegan_sample_data, permutations = 1000,method="bray")
```

```
Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 1000

adonis2(formula = vegan_abundance_mat ~ factor(state) + factor(subplot), data = vegan_sample_data, permutations = 1000, method = "bray", by = "terms")
                Df SumOfSqs      R2      F   Pr(>F)    
factor(state)    1  0.03657 0.03620 0.9571 0.481518    
factor(subplot)  4  0.28593 0.28305 1.8711 0.000999 ***
Residual        18  0.68767 0.68075                    
Total           23  1.01017 1.00000                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

What also strikes me: if I first add variable `subplot` and then `state`, the output does not show variable `state`. Also, the `R2` value of `subplot` is the sum of the R2 value of state and subplot of the previous analysis (=0.03620 + 0.28305):

```
adonis2(vegan_abundance_mat ~ factor(subplot) + factor(state), by="terms",data=vegan_sample_data, permutations = 1000,method="bray")
```

yields:

```
Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 1000

adonis2(formula = vegan_abundance_mat ~ factor(subplot) + factor(state), data = vegan_sample_data, permutations = 1000, method = "bray", by = "terms")
                Df SumOfSqs      R2      F   Pr(>F)    
factor(subplot)  5  0.32250 0.31925 1.6883 0.000999 ***
Residual        18  0.68767 0.68075                    
Total           23  1.01017 1.00000                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Does anyone have an idea what is happening with my 'State' variable in my analyses?

Thank you!

Comment: `factor(state)` gets zero degrees of freedom. Not familiar with this package but it seems you are using too many parameters for the problem at hand.

Comment: @utobi thanks for your answer. Do you have any idea why 0 degrees of freedom are assigned to state, only when testing for marginal effects? (and not when testing sequential effects)

Comment: Subplot is nested within state.  So once subplot is included in a model there is no variance associated with state.  It seems to me that you probably need to account for the study design with some kind of permutation restriction instead of adding more terms to the model, but I'm not an expert in this.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva I think you are right that it has to do with subplot being nested within state. Thank you for the info!